# What does the regular expression [\w-] mean?

Tags: ruby, regex

I checked the documentation, and cannot find what `[\w-]` means. Can anyone tell me what `[\w-]` means in Ruby?

Comment: an alphanumeric symbol or a hyphen

Answer (score 34):

The square brackets `[]` denote a *character class*. A character class will match any of the things inside it.

`\w` is a special class called "word characters". It is shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so it will match:

- `a-z` (all lowercase letters)
- `A-Z` (all uppercase letters)
- `0-9` (all digits)
- `_` (an underscore)

The class you are asking about, `[\w-]`, is a class consisting of `\w` and `-`. So it will match the above list, plus hyphens (`-`).

Exactly as written, `[\w-]`, this regex would match a single character, as long as it's in the above list, or is a dash.

If you were to add a quantifier to the end, e.g. `[\w-]*` or `[\w-]+`, then it would match any of these strings:

```
fooBar9
foo-Bar9
foo-Bar-9
-foo-Bar---9abc__34ab12d
```

And it would partially match these:

```
foo,Bar9                    # match 'foo' - the ',' stops the match
-foo-Bar---9*bc__34ab12d    # match '-foo-Bar---9', the '*' stops the match
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\w  Any word character (letter, number, underscore)
```

Here is what I think it is doing : Go to [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) and try it as follow:

regex_1 `/\w-/`

```
String : f-oo
```

regext_1 will only match `f-`  and will stop right  at `-` ignoring any `\w`  .. the rest of the string `oo`

Whereas :

regex_2  `/[\w-]/`

```
string : f-oo
```

regex_2 will match the entire string plus the special char -  ..  `f-oo`

.. Also , tested the case of a string being like `f-1oo` , and the second regex stopped the match at `f-` Hence, `-` is followed by a `\d`

==========

I belive the whole point of [] is to continue matching before and after `-` . Here are some variations I tried from `irb.`

```
irb(main):004:0> "blah-blah".scan(/\w-/)  
=> ["h-"]
irb(main):005:0> "blah-blah".scan(/[\w-]/)  
=> ["b", "l", "a", "h", "-", "b", "l", "a", "h"]
irb(main):006:0> "blah-blah".scan(/\w-\w/)  
=> ["h-b"]
irb(main):007:0> "blah-blah".scan(/\w-\w*$/)  
=> ["h-blah"]
irb(main):008:0> "blah-blah".scan(/\w*-\w*$/)  
=> ["blah-blah"]
```

Comment: Close - the point of the `[]` is to extend the meaning of `\w` to also include the `-` character.

Comment: Thanks, yep ,  [ ] is to find matching  \w before and after -