# How to modify this hashtag regex to check if the second character is a-z or A-Z?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm building on a regular expression I found that works well for my use case. The purpose is to check for what I consider valid hashtags (I know there's a ton of hashtag regex posts on SO but this question is specific).

Here's the regex I'm using

```
/(^|\B)#(?![0-9_]+\b)([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})(\b|\r)/g
```

The only problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to check if the second character is a-z (the first character would be the hashtag). I only want the first character after the hashtag to be a-z or A-Z. No numbers or non-alphanumeric.

Any help much appreciated, I'm very novice when it comes to regular expressions.

Comment: Replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20}` with `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,19}`?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` checks for lowercase or uppercase letter from A-Z. So, make that the first part of the pattern after `#` then the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20}` with `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,19}` so that the first character is guaranteed to be a letter and then followed by 0 to 19 word characters (alphanumeric or underscore).

However, there are other unnecessary parts in your pattern. It appears that all you need is something like this:

```
/(?:^|\B)#[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,19}\b/g
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CX7gkF/1)**.

**Breakdown of `(?:^|\B)`:**

```python
(?:         # Start of a non-capturing group (don't use a capturing group unless needed).
    ^       # Beginning of the string/line.
    |       # Alternation (OR).
    \B      # The opposite of `\b`. In other words, it makes sure that 
            # the `#` is not preceded by a word character.
)           # End of the non-capturing group.
```

Note: You may also replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with [`\w`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35354636/8967612).

---

### References:

- [Word Boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).
- [Difference between \b and \B in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6664151/8967612).

Comment: Frustratingly simple. I really need to get better at these things. Thanks. A breakdown of this `(?:^|\B)` would be really helpful. I'm guessing it's an `or` statement, saying the beginning of a line, or some kind of boundary...

Answer (score 1):

The below should work.

`(^|\B)#(?![0-9_]+\b)([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,19})(\b|\r)`

If you only want to accept two or more letter hashtags then change `{0,19}` with `{1,19}`.

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com./r/ds4kNn/1)

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern you use `(?![0-9_]+\b)` which asserts that what is directly on the right is not a digit or an underscore and can match a lot of other characters as well besides an upper or lower case a-z.

If you want you can use this part `[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20}` but then you have to use a positive lookahead instead `(?=[a-zA-Z])` to assert what is directly to the right is an upper or lower case a-z.

```
(?:^|\B)#(?=[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DkHNHf/1)